# Why can't I change the font size or type in GD::Graph?

Tags: perl, gd-graph

I'm using the GD::bars module in Perl v 5.8, but I can't seem to get the font size on my graphs x and y labels and values to change. Here's the relevant code I am using:

```
use GD::Graph::bars3d;
use GD::Text;

$my_graph->set_title_font(gdMediumBoldFont, 15); 
$my_graph->set_x_label_font(gdMediumBoldFont, 15); 
$my_graph->set_y_label_font(gdMediumBoldFont, 15); 
$my_graph->set_x_axis_font(gdMediumBoldFont, 15); 
$my_graph->set_y_axis_font(gdMediumBoldFont, 15); 
$my_graph->set_legend_font(gdMediumBoldFont, 15); 

my $plot = $my_graph->plot(\@table_data);
```

I also tried using

```
$my_graph->set_title_font('arial', 15); 
$my_graph->set_x_label_font('arial, 15); 
$my_graph->set_y_label_font('arial, 15); 
$my_graph->set_x_axis_font('arial, 15); 
$my_graph->set_y_axis_font('arial, 15); 
$my_graph->set_legend_font('arial, 15);
```

and setting the font size to a huge number like 60 or something. But there isn't any change at all. I've tried different fonts as well, even trying `/Arial.ttf` but no luck.

Also, I'm saving my graph as a .gif file .

Comment: If you're only using Perl 5.8.0, I *highly* recommend you upgrade -- there are many issues with that version. Also, you should include `use strict; use warnings;` at the top of *every* module and script; there are some errors in the code you pasted above -- it became instantly apparent when I fixed the code formatting and syntax highlighting was activated.

Comment: Hi Ether - It's 5.8.9. I do use warnings, but I didn't mention it in the code snippet above. I just posted those parts which I thought might be relevant to the problem ...

Comment: I figured it out ... its just that there was no arial font installed. I stumbled across a great guide to customizing GD::Graphs and I would recommend it to anyone wanting to get a feel for it: http://wellington.pm.org/archive/201002/grant-gd-graph/toc.html

Comment: You realize `$my_graph->set_x_label_font('arial, 15);` is going to cause some issues, right? Post *only* code you have copied and pasted from a runnable script.

Comment: I missed the end quotation while trying to format the post currently. As I mentioned in my earlier post though, the reason it wasn't working was due to not having the font installed.